# Change 1 point color in scatter plot regardless of color palette

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter

I have a pandas data frame `df` like this

`NAME VALUE ID
  A    0.2  X
  B    0.4  X
  C    0.5  X
  D    0.8  X
      ... 
  Z    0.3  X`

I would like to color all the points by the 'NAME' column by specifying the hue='NAME' but specify the color for ONE point: B.

How do you specify the color for 1 point only, and have the "hue" command take care of the rest (where each point A-Z has a unique color)?

Right now this is my command to plot, where hue is the NAME.

`plot = sns.stripplot(x="ID", y="VALUE", hue="NAME", data=df, jitter=True, c=df['NAME'], s=7, linewidth=1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace one color in the palette by converting it to a list of colors and then replace one of the colors by some other color of your liking.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np;np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

letters = list(map(chr, range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1)))
df = pd.DataFrame({"NAME" : letters, 
                   "VALUE": np.sort(np.random.rand(len(letters)))[::-1],
                   "ID" : ["X"]*len(letters)})

special_letter = "B"
special_color = "indigo"

levels = df["NAME"].unique()
colors = sns.color_palette("hls", len(levels))
inx = list(levels).index(special_letter)
colors[inx] = special_color

ax = sns.stripplot(x="ID", y="VALUE", hue="NAME", data=df, 
                     jitter=True,  s=7, palette=colors)

ax.legend(ncol=3, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05,1), loc=2)
ax.figure.subplots_adjust(right=0.6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Instead of providing a palette directly, one may also (thanks to @mwaskom for pointing that out) use a dictionary of (hue name, color) pairs:

```
levels = df["NAME"].unique()
colors = sns.color_palette("hls", len(levels))
colors = dict(zip(levels, colors))
colors[special_letter] = special_color
```